My ARM Assembly program is giving me a Segmentation Fault and I don't know why - Array Access
I am writing an ARM Assembly program that plays Bulgarian Solitaire. Essentially, it splits 45 "cards" into a random number of piles each with a random number of cards, then methodically begins removing one card at a time from each pile and making a new pile. The game ends when all the cards are in piles of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, and 9, in any order.
However, after printing the initial setup, I get a segmentation fault. Upon using GDB, the description I got was:
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xf7f831b8 in randtbl () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6

Oh, and also, if the initial array is more than 8 elements long, the code just straight up freezes.
My eighteen hours of debugging were completely futile :(
My approach to this problem was as follows:
Create the random array (I was successfully able to do that).
At each step:
Parse through the array, removing 1 from each element. Then, print the array, remove all zero elements, and sort it. Then, check if the array is of the form 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9. If not, restart.
I wrote the following code to do that:
play.s
.cpu cortex-a72
.fpu neon-fp-armv8
.section .data
    finished: .asciz "We finished! Hooray!"
    labelPointerFour: .word 0
.section .text
    .extern printf
    .extern scanf
    .global startPlay
    .type startPlay, %function
startPlay:
    @ Parameters:
    @ r0 = the address of the first location of the array
    @ r1 = the byte offset of the first unfilled byte of the array
    @ Uses:
    @ r0, r4, r5, r6, r7, r8
    push {r4-r10, fp, lr}
    mov fp, sp
@ initialization skipped: r4 is the address of the first element of the array, r5 is the offset, in bytes, assuming a number is 4 bytes of the last element, r6 is a copy of r4, and r9 is the last memory location in the array.
    playLoop:
        
        
        add r9, r4, r5 
        
        mov r8, #0 @ gives r8 a value of zero - it later gets used to be the new pile
        @ r6 is a modifiable copy of r4 and r8 is the counter representing the new pile
        mov r2, #0 
        @ r2 is the counter
        mov r6, r4
        b innerPlayLoop
        innerPlayLoop:
            
            cmp r2, r5 @ if(counter >= offset){postPlay()}
            bge postPlay
            
            ldr r7, [r6]
            sub r7, r7, #1
            add r8, r8, #1
            str r7, [r6]
            
            @ increment counters
            add r6, r6, #4
            add r2, r2, #4
            b innerPlayLoop
        postPlay: 
            str r8, [r9]
            
            
            mov r8, #1
            @ r8 is what we are looking for in nexter
            mov r6, r4
            @ establishing a solid copy of r4
            mov r7, #0
            @ the found flag
            push {r9}
            sub r9, r9, r4
            cmp r9, r5 
            beq addermost
            nextGuy:
            pop {r9}
            
            push {r4, r5, r6}
            mov r0, r4
            mov r1, r5
            bl printArray
            pop {r4, r5, r6}
            push {r4, r5, r6}
            mov r0, r4
            mov r1, r5, lsr #2
            bl removeZero
            pop {r4, r5, r6}
            push {r4, r5, r6}
            mov r0, r4
            mov r1, r5, lsr #2
            bl sort
            pop {r4, r5, r6}
            
            b nexter
        @ important info going into nexter:
        @ r5 is the max offset
        @ r6 is a modifiable copy of r4
        @ r7 is the found flag - make it 1 when you find something of a category
        @ r8 is the current number we're looking for
        @ r9 is the location of zero
        @ r2 is the current number's value
        @ r3 is the current offset
        @ if your search comes up empty, move to playLoop
        nexter:
            mov r7, #0
            
            looperb: @ haha get it? like superb ok i'll stop
                add r8, r8, #1
                mov r3, #0 @ everytime looperb runs, r3 goes to 0
                mov r6, r4
                looperc:
                    ldr r2, [r6]
                    add r6, r6, #4
                    add r3, r3, #4
                    cmp r2, r8
                    beq looperb
                    cmp r8, #10
                    bne looperb
                    cmp r8, #10
                    beq finishedPrinter
                    b looperc
                    
    addermost:
        add r5, r5, #4
        add r9, r9, #4
        b nextGuy
    finishedPrinter:
        ldr r0, =finished
        bl printf
        
            @ begin ending sequence
    mudithu:
    mov fp, sp
    b finisher
    pop {r4-r10, fp, pc}
    

printArray.s
.cpu cortex-a72
.fpu neon-fp-armv8
.section .data
    format: .asciz "%d "
    endFormat: .asciz "\n"
.section .text
    .extern printf
    .extern scanf
    .global printArray
    .type printArray, %function

printArray:
    @ Parameters:
    @ r0 = first memory address of array
    @ r1 = offset of first unfilled element of array
    @ Registers Used:
    @ r0, r1, r4, r5, r6
    push {fp, lr}
    mov fp, sp

    mov r4, r0   @ r4 = current memory address of the element
    mov r5, #0   @ r5 = current offset
    mov r6, r1   @ r6 = max offset

loopThrough:
    cmp r5, r6  @ if current offset >= max offset, end
    bge endPrint
    ldr r0, =format
    ldr r1, [r4]  @ load element value
    bl printf
    add r4, r4, #4  @ move to next element
    add r5, r5, #4  @ increment current offset
    b loopThrough

endPrint:
    ldr r0, =endFormat
    bl printf
    mov sp, fp
    pop {fp, pc}

genRanNum.s
.cpu cortex-a72
.fpu neon-fp-armv8
.section .data
    low: .word 50
    high: .word 100

.section .text
    .extern time
    .extern printf
    .extern srand
    .extern rand
    .global genRanNum
    .type genRanNum, %function

genRanNum:
    @ Input
    @ r0, the low bound
    @ r1, the high bound
    
    @ Registers used (maybe store them)
    @ r0, r1, r2, r3, r5
    
    @ Returns
    @ r0: A random number between the entered r0 and r1, inclusive
    push {r4-r10, fp, lr}
    mov fp, sp
    mov r2, #0
    mov r3, #0
    mov r5, #0
    ldr r3, =low
    str r0, [r3]
    ldr r3, =high
    str r1, [r3]

    mov r0, #0
    bl time
    push {r0}
    bl srand
    pop {r0}
    bl rand
    @ r0 contains a big random number
    
    ldr r1, =low
    ldr r2, =high
    ldr r1, [r1]
    ldr r2, [r2]
    @ now start modulus division
    sub r5, r2, r1
    add r5, r5, #1
    modLoop:
        cmp r0, r5
        blt addX
        sub r0, r0, r5
        b modLoop
    addX:
        
        add r2, r0, r1
    @ r2 now contains a random number between low and high
        mov r0, r2
        mov sp, fp
        pop {r4-r10, fp, pc}


        


Any help would be appreciated.
I know that the error happens somewhere within play.s through some debugging. However, the debugger only tells me that randTbl is what is throwing the fault.
Thank you so much! Your help would literally save me.
EDIT:
Compiled using gcc -o l4 *file names here* -g

Since the code fails in randtbl, it seems strange that you didn't show us the code that calls random.  How are you compiling this?  Are you initializing the C runtime library?

Since you are already using a debugger, at least print out which instruction is faulting. Also start stepping through the code from the beginning and see where it goes wrong. Just because some other code you claim is "confirmed working" does not mean those parts are correct and will work under different circumstances. You should provide a [mcve]. Do not just dump all your code.

Yes, the C runtime library is initialized.

"I have NO CLUE which part is giving me the error!" — that's what debugging is for, to narrow down where it is going wrong and then figure out why.

I have done some editing to improve my question! Sorry about the ambiguity :)
